# Is python module namespace itself an object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Each module when imported, the code in the module gets executed and Python creates a new namespace for all the objects which are defined in the new module.

Is python module namespace itself an object in python?

Comment: In python everything is an object.

Comment: Yes, it's the namespace of the module object. It is precisely the dict returned by `globals()`

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu: That's a completely unrelated thing.